# What does "bright topaz denizens of a world of green" mean

Tags: meaning, poetry, literature, poetic

Here is an extract from the poem "Aunt Jennifer's tigers" by Adrienne Rich:

> Aunt Jennifer's tigers prance across a screen
> bright topaz denizens of a world of green.
> They do not fear the men beneath the tree.

In the above extract, what does the sentence "bright topaz denizens of a world of green" mean?
I did not find any relation between the words 'topaz' and 'denizens'.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denizen (inhabitant). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/topaz (a gem stone that comes in many colours, but is often yellowish-orange).

Comment: @Frank  As I've mentioned in the details, I am aware of those meanings, but can you please explain what the sentence means? I don't find any link between those two words...

Comment: There's no link really - it's just a description of tigers: _bright topaz_ being the colour of their fur and _denizen_ indicating they live in _the world of green_ (presumably a jungle). She could have written _orange residents of the jungle_ but that is not very poetic.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now - are you reading it as _bright topaz-denizens_ rather than _bright-topaz denizens_?

Comment: Hmmm...you're right, I got it now, thank you frank.

Comment: Part of the reason the poet uses those words is for the duplicated z sound. Also, *topaz denizen* is exotic and exciting, like the tigers, and in contrast to Aunt Jennifer's unfulfilling life.

Comment: Is interpretation of verse not OT on ELU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Topaz is a gemstone. I had thought it was usually Blue, but some research shows that it can be various shades of orange and brown as well. Wikipedia says:

> Orange topaz, also known as precious topaz, is the traditional
>   November birthstone, the symbol of friendship

So we have beautiful, hard, crystalline, light refracting, light reflecting orange tigers living in (denizens of) a world of green ... I think of forests ...

Compare with William Blake's

> Tyger Tyger, burning bright,
>   In the forests of the night;
>   What immortal hand or eye,
>   Could frame thy fearful symmetry

Answer (score 3):

Wonderful reference site for poem analysis: http://www.shmoop.com/aunt-jennifers-tigers/

Specific link here; read the explanation, - http://www.shmoop.com/aunt-jennifers-tigers/stanza-1-summary.html

**Quote**: *A few vocab words are in order here. First: a topaz is a shiny crystal, and denizen means an inhabitant. So, to rephrase the poem a bit: the tigers are bright, crystalline animals that prance around their "world of green." What world might this be? We're guessing it's a forest, where tigers like to do their tiger-ly thing.
Though they only appear on some screen, these tigers seem pretty alive to us. They are bright and crystal-like, and they prance. Rich's colorful imagery is really vivid here.*

Comment: I've edited it.